# I have a data of list which I have to insert it in database using jdbc

Tags: java

I have a data of list which I have to insert it in database using jdbc. My problem is that the size of list is not always constant, sometimes it gives `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExp`. So I need to insert the record dynamically.

Currently I am inserting records for list size 10, now if I get list of size 5 then?

```
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int ean) throws SQLException {

    ps.setLong(1,Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate (including java 8 streams methods) through the list:

```
List<String> columnsList = mpGeometryBeanList.get(mpGeometryBeanIndex);
for(int i = 0; i < columnsList.size(); i++){
  ps.setString(i + 2, columnsList.get(i));
}
```

Or you can probably change your prepared statement to accept list value (need to see more code)

Comment: My query is INSERT INTO ATTACHMENT_LAYER_INFO values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; so how can query be created dynamically depending upon size

Answer (score 0):

Use the for loop.

```
ps.setLong(1,attachmetId);
for(int i=0; i<mpGeometryBeanList.get(mpGeometryBeanIndex).getColumnList().size(): i++){
    ps.setString(i+2,mpGeometryBeanList.get(mpGeometryBeanIndex).getColumnList().get(i));
}
```

Comment: My query is INSERT INTO ATTACHMENT_LAYER_INFO values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; so how can query be created dynamically depending upon size

Comment: Use StringBuilder to append the number of '?' you want. That is, if your list is of size n, then append n number of '?' into the query by running a loop.